# как сделать кнопку не активную

Tags: c#, unity3d

как сделать чтоб при нажатие на кнопку (button_1) один раз она нажималась , а после становилась неактивной и не нажималась совсем?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
    
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Money;
    private int MoneyUp = 20;
    
    private bool Check = true;
    
    public Text MoneyText;
    public Text Purch;
    public GameObject ShopPan;
    public GameObject Button_1;
    
    void Update()
    {
        MoneyText.text = Money + "$";
    }
    
    public void OnClickButton()
    {
        Money += MoneyUp;
    }
    
    public void OnClickInfoButton()
    {
        if (Check == true)
        {
            ShopPan.SetActive(true);
            Check = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ShopPan.SetActive(false);
            Check = true;
        }
    }
    
    public void OnClickShopButton()
    {
        if(Check == true)
        {
            ShopPan.SetActive(true);
            Check = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ShopPan.SetActive(false);
            Check = true;
        }
    }
    
    public void OnClickBuy()
    {
        if(Money >= 20)
        {
            MoneyUp += 1;
            Money -= 20;
    
            if (Check == true)
            {
                Button_1.SetActive(false);
                Check = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Button_1.SetActive(true);
                Check = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void OnClickBuy_1()
    {
        if (Money >= 50)
        {
            MoneyUp += 1;
            Money -= 50;
        }
    }
    
    public void OnClickBuy_2()
    {
        if (Money >= 90)
        {
            MoneyUp += 2;
            Money -= 90;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Смысл вам отвечать если ответ на прошлый вопрос вы благополучно проигнорировали, пришлось его удалить.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `buttonName` имя объекта кнопки.

У каждого button есть свойство `Enabled`, при `true` - кнопку можно нажимать, при `false` - кнопку нажать нельзя.

```
buttonName.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Вы перепутали Unity и Winforms.

Comment: А если так?
```public void BtnOnClick() { gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false; }```

Comment: Пытаетесь угадать, но пока не получается. Но мысль верная.

Comment: Обратите внимание на `Button_1` и ее тип. Поле просто не того типа, надо поменять на `Button`, и тогда можно будет дергать interactable. Примерно про это должен быть ваш ответ. Я просто уже отвечал автору, и код про это показыал, но он забил и пошел другой вопрос создавать. Скорее всего и на этот ответ не отреагирует никак.

Comment: @aepot понял, я в Unity не силён, просто помочь хотел хотя бы на мысль натолкнуть. По документации глянул примерно и по уже задаваемым вопросам

Comment: Ну так либо исправьте ответ,либо удалите тогда.